# Open interval is an open set; with open rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I am trying to prove that the open interval in $R^n$ is an open set. The book I am using uses "open rectangles" rather than "open balls".

> [image]

**EDIT**: I figured out the $2$, but the $\sqrt{n}$ is still a mystery to me.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture in the case $n=2$? If you do, I think that you’ll see where the $2$ comes from. The $\sqrt{n}$ is the length of the long diagonal of the unit $n$-cube in $\Bbb R^n$: scaling down by a factor of $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ gives you the half-side of the largest $n$-cube centred at $x$ and with sides parallel to the axes that will fit inside $U$.

Comment: Note that $U$ is called an open ball, when it is in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, you are correct. I did draw a picture, but I later found out that I drew a circle inside of a square and hence my geometry never could have made sense. My new picture has a square inside a circle now. I do not understand your explanation for the $\sqrt{n}$ factor. I tried $n = 2$ and I am guessing it has to do with a triangle. Let me attach a picture

Comment: @sidht: The square inside the circle is right. Draw a horizontal line from the centre of the square and circle to the righthand side of the square, and draw another line from the centre to the upper righthand corner of the square. By the Pythagorean theorem the length of the first line is $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ times the length of the second. Thus, if you divide the radius of the circle by $\sqrt2$, you get half the side of the square. Now imagine doing the same thing with a cube inside a sphere: the length of the line from the centre out to the righthand wall of the cube is ...

Comment: ... $\frac1{\sqrt3}$ times the length of the line from the centre to one of the upper corners of the cube. Thus, half the side of the cube is $\frac1{\sqrt3}$ times the radius of the sphere. In general, the factor turns out to be $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I am getting $\sqrt{2}$, but it isn't where you are talking about. I don't understand why you want a horizontal line from the center of the circle as well. The diagonal from the center of the square to the upper right is $\sqrt{2(r - |x -a|)^2} = \sqrt{2}(r - |x -a|)$